# Qt: How to place widgets in layout with minWidth and percentage based proportions all together

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I have a `QHBoxLayout` and I want to add 3 widgets inside.

```
QLabel + QLineEdit + Image (QLabel + QImage)
```

I need `QLabel` to have a `setMinWidth of 100 pixels`
I need `QImage` to have a **fixed Width**
I need `QLineEdit` to use **all the available space left in the middle**

Now I want `QLabel`'s space to be **either**: **100 pixels** minimum or **15%,** whichever **is larger**.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: ``QImage`` in ``QLabel``?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Bakuriu: I did the obvious two. A) Try to search on Google and check the documentation. I did not find something that covered both percentage and setting minimum width in pixels, so I asked here. Since this is a relatively simple Knowledge question (no "logic" required) I did not think I would need to state the two obvious. I appreciate your help and suggestion for future. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [setStretchFactor](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#setStretchFactor):

```
layout->setStretchFactor(label, 15)
layout->setStretchFactor(line, 100)
```